# Perforce Translation of file error while Synching in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, perforce

```
My Jenkins Version: 2.46.2- LTS.
Jenkins OS: Ubuntu (This is Jenkins Master Server).
Perforce Plugin Version: 1.7.5
Slave Machine: OS Windows-7 (64Bit).
Perforce Visual Client Version: 2016.2
```

I have configured perforce to sync the code to slave machine from master server. But when i tried to download it shows below errors.

**Jenkins Errors:-**

> Caught exception communicating with perforce.Error encountered while
> force synching. Error: Translation of file content failed near Line.

Due to this i m unable to download the files.So any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a Unicode translation error.  Setting P4CHARSET to a different value may help, but if the files are corrupted on the back end (i.e. they aren't valid utf8, which is how the server normalizes its copy of all Unicode files) then it won't matter what you set on the client.

Good troubleshooting steps would be to try syncing the same file to another client, and to look in the history for the originally submitting client and try to figure out what character set it was using.